# Creating a mask or code to simplify reading a 16 error bit parsing. Python

Tags: python

I'm still learning the python language and I was tasked with something I'm not familiar with. What I am trying to do is to create a code or library that is able to read from a register an error integer either in binary or hex and from that signal have it show on a tkinter gui the errors that occur. For example, on bit 1 it's overtemp, bit 2 is overcurrent,.....bit 11 is tank overcurrent. So that if a signal such as 0000000000001011, it will show that 3 errors have occurred while the program is running.

The only possible way I see is to create a large if/elif statement in which you compare every single bit combination from 0x0001 up to 0xffff. Does anyone know of a python library available or a simple mask/code that could be used so that I don't have to worry about creating every single combination possible from 0x0001 up to 0xffff.

Or if possible is there a way so that the integer runs through a code where it compares each number and determines if there is a one or not. If there is a one, it will then display the error message associated if the individual bit.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do it.  You don't have to test every bit combination, just each individual bit (16 in your 0000-ffff case).  Here are a couple of ways illustrated with 4 bits:

1. Use the built-in `enum.Flag` type.  Below creates an `Error` class and defines each of the bits with some name.  Create an instance of the class with the error value and printing it will show you the flags in the value.  Test for a particular flag by bitwise-ANDing with the flag.  Note that `auto` generates the bit values automatically, vs. assigning 1,2,4,8,etc. directly.

```py
from enum import Flag,auto

class Error(Flag):
    NotFound = auto()  # bit 0, value 1
    BadValue = auto()  # bit 1, value 2
    ReadOnly = auto()  # bit 2, value 4
    Error = auto()     # bit 3, value 8, etc.

f = Error(0b1101)
print(f)
for bit in Error:
    if f & bit:
        print(f'bit value {bit.value}: {bit.name}')
```

Output:

```
Error.Error|ReadOnly|NotFound
bit value 1: NotFound
bit value 4: ReadOnly
bit value 8: Error
```

2. Test for the bits manually. `1 << n` creates a bit in the nth position.  Bit-wise ANDing that value with the error message will be non-zero if the bit is set in the error value:

```py
err = 0b1101
bit_desc = 'not found','bad value','read only','error'
for bit in range(4):
    if err & (1 << bit):
        print(bit_desc[bit])
```

Output:

```
not found
read only
error
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was hoping for and it works like a charm!